# Windows vista CD Autorun does not execute

Tags: windows, autorun

I have three files
1. index.htm
2. autoplay.exe (I have written this to run index.htm in the root folder using default browser.)
3. autorun.inf:

```
[autorun] 
Open=autoplay.exe
Label=My Presentation
Action=Run my presentation
Publisher=Ali Habibzadeh
```

I have copied this to a blank cd but it only triggers the autoplay dialog rather than actually auto playing my index.htm

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **Windows is overriding autorun behaviour of CD** and it's giving you all possible options you may want to do with the CD or the content of the CD.

You will find an autorun option in the list if you click on this you'll get to execute autorun for your CD. In the windows CD options dialog you can check if you want to always-autorun for the CD. Check that option and next time it will perform autorun and not display windows CD action options.

> **However this will remain local and if
>   you use this CD on other machine the
>   same steps will need to be repeated.**

vista has strict security options which adds this dialog before autorun. And even if you do autorun you'll be required to grant security prompt to let the autorun go ahead and execute.

> **There's nothing much you can do in this case.**

Comment: I am quite disappointed that there is no way to force an automatic play for things such as a multimedia presentation etc.

but it makes sense if windows behaves anal regarding user permission.

Comment: Which version of windows are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
[autorun]
Open=
shellexecute="index.htm"
```

Works for me using a thumbdrive on Vista.

More info on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776823%28VS.85%29.aspx#Shellexecute).

Comment: @this.__curious_geek: I've updated my post. Not sure if it works on different Windows version or from a CD though.

Comment: shellexecute is the same. just for non exe files to run with associated app. But nothing seems to have absolute power to guarantee that when you insert cd for user to no do anything but watch the presentation.

Comment: Well I guess "absolute power" is not always welcomed. Sorry mate, can't be of much help here.

Comment: var virtualHand = new virtualhand();
function runPres() {
   virtualHand.comeOutofScreen(clickAutoRun);
}
runPres();
lol